What's the difference between PBR (pointed based rendering) and GS (Gaussian Splatting)
Over 20 years ago, there was a wave of "Point-Based Rendering" (PBR) or even "Point-Based Graphics". It started with two interesting papers, both published on SIGGRAPH 2000, "QSplat" from Stanford (https://doi.org/10.1145/344779.344940) and "Surfel" from ETH (https://doi.org/10.1145/344779.344936). After that, it was very popular in several years. I remember there are even a "Symposium on Point-Based Graphics" series lasting for a few years. However, after several years, PBR got cool down and no one mentioned PBR any more.
In last year's SIGGRAPH, suddenly, GS (Gaussian Splatting) (https://doi.org/10.1145/3592433) becomes hot, and everyone talks about GS now. In my point of view, GS is just PBR. But it must has some differences to PBR, so that it can become hot again after so many years. So my questions are:

What is the difference between PBR and GS?
Why did PBR get cool down in last wave?
Are the reasons that make PBR cool down still valid now? Why is GS not affected by them?

